# when the checkboxes is On then write Text to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have two sheets **sheet1 = "output"** and **sheet2= "input"**. In **sheet2** there are multiple checkbox assign to some certain variable. for example:

|  | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | flow | checkbox1 |
| 3 | speed | checkbox5 |
| 4 | pressure discharge | checkbox6 |
| 5 | pressure suction | checkbox7 |
| 6 | fill level | checkbox13 |

Now what I want is if any checkbox is On then write its variable name to **Sheet1** at specific cell reference else leave the cell blank

Let us say that if **checkbox1**, **checkbox3** and **checkbox4** is On then write **"flow", "size" and "current"** in cell B2, B4, B5 of **sheet1** and write **"XYZ"** in cell B1. The **sheet1 = output** should look like:

|  | B |
| --- | --- |
| 42 | flow |
| 43 | speed |
| 44 | pressure discharge |
| 45 | pressure suction |
| 46 | fill level |

So far what i defined:

```
Sub chart()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim check1 As Boolean, check2 As Boolean, check3 As Boolean, check4 As Boolean

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

check1 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
check2 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 2").Value = xlOn
check3 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 3").Value = xlOn
check4 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 4").Value = xlOn

End Sub`
```

Now i want to write if condition.

Comment: Please, show us what you tried by your own! How did you "assign" variables to check boxes? You do not show the rows and columns headers. What column is the one keeping strings? Are there more than 4 such check boxes? "B:B"? Are all check boxes placed in column C:C? For instance, is the "flow" string in the second row? What kind of check boxes do you use? ActiveX type?

Comment: I have edit the post please check if you got your answer :) I have more the 4 check boxes.

Comment: If it looks complicated to answer my clear questions, I wish you luck in solving your code! Your edit does not clarify too much.

Comment: can you please have a look now :(

Comment: **How did you "assign" variables to check boxes? You do not show the rows and columns headers. What column is the one keeping strings? Are there more than 4 such check boxes? "B:B"? Are all check boxes placed in column C:C? For instance, is the "flow" string in the second row? What kind of check boxes do you use? ActiveX type?**

Comment: If there are, or will be more than 4 such check boxes, the code must be structured in a different way than allocating a boolean variable for each.

Comment: please have a look now, for checkbox i used  **Developer Tab –> Controls –> Insert –> Form Controls –> Check Box**

Comment: So, Form controls... I will place an answer able to be used for as many check boxes will exist, of course, if the row number correspond with the check boxes naming way...

Comment: Please, test the code I placed in my answer and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It works for `Form` check boxes type and needs a correspondence between the text box name and the word in B:B to be returned. I am talking about **their name** (in the left address text box), not their caption (obtained by editing of the automated allocated one). I this way, you can use as many check boxes you want. Only to have their name correlate with the row where the string to be returned exists:

```
Sub WriteOnChckBoxFVal()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long
   
   Set sh1 = ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
   Set sh2 = sh1.Next     'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
   lastR = sh1.Range("B" & sh1.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh1.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Value2
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If sh1.CheckBoxes("Check Box " & i).value = 1 Then
            arrFin(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        Else
            arrFin(i, 1) = "XYZ"
        End If
   Next i
   'drop the array content at once:
   sh2.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).value = arrFin
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

The next version also works on any number of check boxes, having their nume in any way, but **their top left corner to be placed in column C:C, and on the row of the string to be returned**. If gaps will exist, the returned array will be decalate starting from the row with the gap...:

```
Private Sub BringSensorsByChkBoxesVal()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
   Const colLet As String = "G"
   
   Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
   Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
   lastR = sh1.Range("B" & sh1.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   arr = sh1.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Value2
   ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To sh1.CheckBoxes.count
        'process only Form check boxes located in C:C column:
        If Not Intersect(sh1.CheckBoxes(i).TopLeftCell, sh1.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
            dict(sh1.CheckBoxes(i).TopLeftCell.Row) = _
                      IIf(sh1.CheckBoxes(i).value = 1, sh1.Range("B" & sh1.CheckBoxes(i).TopLeftCell.Row).value, "XYZ")
        End If
   Next i
   Set dict = sortDictionaryByKeys(dict) 'sort dictionary  by keys

   'drop the dictionary items at once:
   sh2.Range("B2").Resize(dict.count, 1).value = Application.Transpose(dict.Items)
   MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Private Function sortDictionaryByKeys(dict As Object, Optional boolAsccend As Boolean = True) As Object 'sorting a dictionary
    Dim arrDict, tmpKey, i As Long, j As Long

    'Only sort if more than one item in the dict
    If dict.count < 1 Then Set sortDictionaryByKeys = dict: Exit Function
    
    'place the dict keys in an array:
    arrDict = dict.Keys

    'Do the bubble sort of the array:
    For i = 0 To (dict.count - 2)
        For j = i + 1 To dict.count - 1
            If IIf(boolAsccend, arrDict(i) > arrDict(j), arrDict(i) < arrDict(j)) Then
                tmpKey = arrDict(j): arrDict(j) = arrDict(i)
                arrDict(i) = tmpKey
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'Create the new dictionary and load it using arrDict keys and dict items:
    Set sortDictionaryByKeys = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 0 To (dict.count - 1)
        sortDictionaryByKeys.Add arrDict(i), dict(arrDict(i))
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: @wasif ahmed Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need? You looked anxios to receive a solution...

Comment: Unfortunately things are not working :( where I can share the images of my shet to you please let me know for better understanding

Comment: @wasif No need to share anything, I think. If the code returns an error, you should mention what error and **the code line where it is raised**, But now I must leave my office and I can look on your comment only after some hours when I will be at home. If you will do i know, I may stay some minutes, but it is at least polite to send some feedback when you receives an answer.. I placed the answer 43 minutes before...

Comment: It gave  a error on line 9 "the item with the specified name was not found"

Comment: Then, this only means that there is no correspondence between the checkbox **name** and what you show. When the code is stopped on error, please move the cursor over `i` variable and you will see that a check box named as "Check Box i" does not exist. Right click to the one **you think it should be** (having only its caption modified) and correct its name in the left address text box, then press Enter... Now I am leaving.

Comment: @wasif Did you try what I suggested above? The code works **only if the processed sheet is consistent**! I mean, for each string in column "A:A" must exist a check box having the numeric part from its name equal with the row where it is placed - 1**. Even if the placement can be anywhere, the numeric value must exist for **all existing strings/rows in "A:A"**.

Comment: I have add some picture to my post can you please look over that once this will give you a clear image that what actually i am trying to do.I want to add Regarding the check boxes number  that they are not (i+1) they are quite random, for example if one check box number is 3 then the other check box number is 20.

Comment: I just want like when i make checks=true on sheet2 then on sheet1 the name of sensors comes automatically.

Comment: @wasif At least, can you state that all check boxes in the respective sheet are located in the column C:C, no other check boxes exist and they are located on the row where from the string in A:A column to be returned? Do you understand what I am asking?

Comment: all the check boxes are on the same column i.e C:C, yes i clearly got your point :)

Comment: @wasif  When I said **check boxes in the respective sheet to be located in the column C:C** I meant that their top left corner is mandatory to be placed on C:C column and **on the row of the string/sensor to be returned**. Is this your case? Please, check that and correct, if necessary. Not only the box where to be checked! The whole text box, especially **its top left corner**... I will start preparing an answer. I will use a dictionary and I already have a function sorting such an object. It will not take me too long, I hope

Comment: please check my answer that I added to this post, t is also showing me the output i wanted , but to me it really seem to be a beginner Programm.  could you help me out to get rid of this multiple if statement?

Comment: @wasif I edited my answer and placed a more complex version processing only the check boxes from C:C column, **their positioning to be done according to what I specified above**. Please, check it and send some feedback.

Comment: @wasif No offence, but your code is primitive, needing to continuously be updated in case of a new string - check box combination. If you insert a row, it will be a pain in the ass to adapt it, too.

Comment: you are absolutely correct it will be a bad pain, I am going through your code and trying to adapt it :)

Comment: @wasif What to adapt **in code**? You should only take care that your check boxes respect the rule stated three times... Only after that you should try understanding the code and adapt something, if the case..

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this (assuming checkboxes are in ws2):

```
sub code()
Dim ws as worksheet: set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("input")
Dim ws2 as worksheet: set ws2 = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("output")

   With ws2
      If .OLEObjects("checkbox1").Object.Value = True And _
         .OLEObjects("checkbox2").Object.Value = True And _
         .OLEObjects("checkbox3").Object.Value = True Then

          ws.Range("B1").Value = "current"
          ws.Range("B2").Value = "flow"
          ws.Range("B2").Value = "size"
          ws.Range("B2").Value = "current"
      end if
   end with      
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub main_process_data()
 Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
 Dim check1 As Boolean, check5 As Boolean, check6 As Boolean, check7 As Boolean, check13 As Boolean

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

check1 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
check5 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 5").Value = xlOn
check6 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 6").Value = xlOn
check7 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 7").Value = xlOn
check13 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 13").Value = xlOn

If check1 Then
    s1.Range("C42").Value = s2.Range("B2").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C42").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check5 Then
    s1.Range("C43").Value = s2.Range("B3").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C43").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check6 Then
    s1.Range("C44").Value = s2.Range("B4").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C44").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check7 Then
    s1.Range("C45").Value = s2.Range("B5").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C45").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check13 Then
    s1.Range("C46").Value = s2.Range("B11").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C46").Value = vbNullString
End If




End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).